# Kombu Consumer as Thrift Service

Tags: python, rabbitmq, thrift, kombu

I need to build a Kombu consumer which can be controlled programatically. All the examples I've seen are just trivial ones that tell you to use ctrl-c to stop the program.

My main application is running as a Twisted Thrift service and I'm thinking that I can somehow use Twisted reactor to deal with the eventloop inside my consumer but I can't figure out how.

Here is my consumer class. The start_consuming() part is fine except that it's blocking and I cannot call stop_consuming() from the outside.

```
from kombu import BrokerConnection, Exchange, eventloop, Queue, Consumer


class DMS():
    __routing_key = None
    __is_consuming = None
    __message_counter = 0

    def __init__(self, routing_key):
        print 'server: __init__()'
        self.__routing_key = routing_key

    def __handle_message(self, body, message):
        self.__message_counter += 1

        # Print count every 10,000 messsages.
        if (self.__message_counter % 10000) == 0:
            print self.__message_counter

    def start_consuming(self):
        print 'server: start_consuming()'
        self.__is_consuming = True
        exchange = Exchange('raven-exchange', type='topic', durable=False)
        queue = Queue(self.__routing_key, exchange, routing_key=self.__routing_key)

        with BrokerConnection('amqp://guest:guest@10.1.1.121:5672//') as connection:
            with Consumer(connection, queue, callbacks=[self.__handle_message]) as consumer:
                for _ in eventloop(connection):

                    if self.__is_consuming:
                        pass
                    else:
                        break

                consumer.cancel()
            connection.close()

    def stop_consuming(self):
        print 'server: stop_consuming()'
        self.__is_consuming = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to route Thrift service calls through a MQ system is via `oneway` calls, because that is the most natural way to communicate via MQ and MessageBus systems.

```
struct Foo {
  1: string whoa
  2: i32 counter
}

service Whatever {
    oneway void FooBar(1: Foo someData, 2:i32 moreData)
}
```

A `oneway` call is a special form of a Thrift RPC call: As the name suggests, the call goes only in one direction. Neither return values nor exceptions (which are actually return values) are used with `oneway`. The call does send only the input args and does not wait for any values in return.

In order to establish a bi-di communication, the client needs to implement a similar service, designed to receive incoming answer messages. There are some samples in the [Thrift `/contrib` folder](https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/contrib), featuring 0MQ, Rebus and Stomp. Although they do not specifically deal with Python, the main idea should become clear.